# I don't want psycopg2 to escape new line character (\n) in query result

Tags: python, python-3.x, psycopg2, psycopg

I have some records data with `\n`. When I do a SELECT query using psycopg2 the result comes with `\n` escaped like this `\\n`. I want the result have literal `\n` in order to use `splitlines()`.

Comment: Can you try iterating through and removing any instances of leading slashes?

Comment: When I run the query in `psql` the result is as I want, so I think the problem is not the data itself. I can use `split('\\n')` but I don't want to do this way.

Comment: Why do you not want to do it that way? Are you trying to avoid iterating over all the code?

Comment: Because I could have two SQL backends, MySQL or PostgreSQL, using the first I don't get this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that values were edited with pgadmin3 (incorrectly, the correct way is shift+enter to add a new line). I asked the user to use phppgadmin (easier for him, multiline fields are edited with textarea control) and now everything is working properly.

So pyscopg2 **WORKS** fine, I'm sorry to thought it was the culprit.

He was putting literals `\n` in order to put new lines.

Answer (score -1):

Try this: `object.replace("\\n", r"\n")`

Hope this helped :)

Comment: I would like to solve the issue using psycopg2 (I think it's the one to blame) instead of Python itself.

Comment: @oneohthree Unfortunately i don't think you'll be able to do that, since \n is a special character it outputs it as \\n. I think you'll have to solve it that way or using some other method.

Comment: Using the same data but with MySQL I get literal `\n`.

Comment: @oneohthree Why use psycopg2 then?

Comment: It's a matter of choice, the user can use MySQL or PostgreSQL.

Comment: @oneohthree Okay I see. I can't help you then since i don't have much experience with the module

Comment: That's not going to do anything: `"\\n" == r"\n"`